# Mergin db sync fails to start

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mergin-maps, db-sync

I actually experiencing two type of issues. I am using DB-SYNC 2.1.1 on Windows.

I have couple of tables in a database and I am actively using row level security, to modify the availability of data to field users.
Whenever I try to sync a table with activated row level security the db sync fails as it tries to add the id column two times:

`Error: postgres cmd error: ERROR:  column "ogc_fid" specified more than once`

so I removed all the privileges setup, it did fail. I tried with `postgres` user it did fail. I removed my orignal id column and added uuid field with uuid_generate_v4() this helped to generate another error

```
LINE 1: UPDATE "public_db_sync"."chambers_mergin" SET  WHERE "uuid2"...
                                                       ^
SQL:
UPDATE "public_db_sync"."chambers_mergin" SET  WHERE "uuid2" = 'ffdc0ee4-6fd8-4e90-a5e3-32a975efc37c'
```

What is wrong?